# Data from Web Power query is not refreshing on MacBook Pro

Tags: excel, macos, powerquery

I got data from a website by using a web query on a Windows computer. After I got the data I saved the file and sent it to my Mac. When I attempted to refresh the Excel sheet it told me this

Expression.Error] The import Web.Page matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?
[image]

Below is the query. Works fine on Windows computers.

```
let

    SvcUrl = "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token?refresh_token=****.******47892*******************&client_id=*********&client_secret=*********&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com&grant_type=refresh_token",

    Content = "{}",

    Response= Web.Contents(SvcUrl, 

    [
    Content=Text.ToBinary(Content),
    Headers=[#"Content-Type" = "application/json"]
    ]
    ),

    Json = Json.Document(Response),
    AccessToken = Json[access_token],
    AccessTokenHeader = "Zoho-oauthtoken " & AccessToken,
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.zohoapis.com/invoice/v3/customerpayments", [Headers=[Authorization=AccessTokenHeader, #"X-com-zoho-invoice-organizationid"="76077****", #"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"]])),
    customerpayments1 = Source[customerpayments],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(customerpayments1, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"payment_id", "payment_number", "invoice_numbers", "date", "payment_mode", "payment_mode_formatted", "amount", "bcy_amount", "unused_amount", "bcy_unused_amount", "description", "reference_number", "customer_id", "customer_name", "created_time", "last_modified_time", "last_four_digits", "gateway_transaction_id", "payment_gateway", "bcy_refunded_amount", "applied_invoices", "has_attachment", "documents", "custom_fields_list", "tax_amount_withheld", "payment_type", "settlement_status"}, {"Column1.payment_id", "Column1.payment_number", "Column1.invoice_numbers", "Column1.date", "Column1.payment_mode", "Column1.payment_mode_formatted", "Column1.amount", "Column1.bcy_amount", "Column1.unused_amount", "Column1.bcy_unused_amount", "Column1.description", "Column1.reference_number", "Column1.customer_id", "Column1.customer_name", "Column1.created_time", "Column1.last_modified_time", "Column1.last_four_digits", "Column1.gateway_transaction_id", "Column1.payment_gateway", "Column1.bcy_refunded_amount", "Column1.applied_invoices", "Column1.has_attachment", "Column1.documents", "Column1.custom_fields_list", "Column1.tax_amount_withheld", "Column1.payment_type", "Column1.settlement_status"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

Comment: And it works on Windows?

Comment: Yes, It works fine on Windows. The reason why I couldn't find or get any error.

Answer (score 0):

Excel for Mac is basically a stunted version of Excel for Windows. Personally, I would not use Excel on a Mac but for very basic stuff for that reason.

Among others, it does not provide the same list of connectors that the Windows version has. Connecting to a web resource is currently not supported ([see also this thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/get-external-data-from-web-not-showing/m-p/414906)).

When you start a new query in Power Query, you are establishing a data connection to whatever source you picked. You do that via the "get data" feature, and when you do, you are prompted for connection settings, for example a user name/password etc. This is an example:

[image: screenshot power query]

You likely realized that the connector was not available in Excel for Mac and figured, let's just take the Windows query, open a blank query on Mac and it should just work. The reason it doesn't is that you have not established a connection in Power Query. You are listing one in your query M code, but Power Query does not know the source exists, hence the error you are getting.

All I could find was [this workaround](https://www.wikihow.com/Import-Web-Data-Into-Excel-on-PC-or-Mac), but I have not tested it myself.